# Hibernate 5: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-5.x

The following code works just fine with Hibernate 4.3, but when I try the same code using Hibernate 5.0 it results in the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: entity.Message
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:776)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1451)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:678)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:670)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:665)
    at client.Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

Could somebody help me understand why is it happening?

---

**Following is the code being used to test the example:**

**Main.java**

```
package client;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import util.HibernateUtil;
import entity.Message;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Message message = new Message( "Hello Hibernate 5" );

        session.save(message);    

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();    
    }
}
```

**HibernateUtil.java**

```
package util;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {    
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();    
    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {           
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");     
            return configuration.buildSessionFactory( new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings( configuration.getProperties() ).build() );
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {                
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }   
}
```

**Message.java**

```
package entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="message")
public class Message {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="ID")  
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="TEXT")    
    private String text;

    public Message() {}
    public Message(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }   
}
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hello</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">pass</property>

        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <mapping class="entity.Message"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**SQL Database Schema (RDBMS: MYSQL)**

```
CREATE DATABASE `hello`;
USE `hello`;
CREATE TABLE `message` (
`ID` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`TEXT` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);
```

Comment: what is your directory structure

Comment: @JunedAhsan: Its a Java Project in Eclipse IDE with `src` being the source folder in the classpath. `hibernate.cfg.xml` is right under the `src` folder. `Main.java` is in the `client` package, `HibernateUtil.java` in `util` package and `Message.java` in the `entity` package.

Comment: I think its because you didnt set up a default schema property in your hibernate-cfg.xml. Let me take a look, and I'll be right back with the answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

UPDATED: In Hibernate 5.0.x, configuration with standard service registry is **deprecated**

Instead you should bootstrap it with **Metadata**:

In your `HibernateUtil` class, you should add

```
   private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {           
        StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
        .configure( "hibernate.cfg.xml" )
        .build();

        Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources( standardRegistry )
        .getMetadataBuilder()
        .build();

        return metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();

    }
```

And as a side note, change the ID declaration of your Message Class to

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="ID")  
private Long id;
```

So hibernate can properly use mySql's auto increment, otherwise it will throw an exception.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference. I am stilling getting the same error.

Comment: ok, im setting up a new project in order to debug it, are you using maven?

Comment: not to sound like an ass, but I recreated your project in eclipse and it worked perfectly. I shared it on github: https://github.com/bruno-cw/pizzadepot/tree/master/Hibernate

if you could share yours, it would be a great help to identify whats wrong.
I ruled out any problem with db,

Comment: No, am not using Maven. Just a Java project in eclipse with jar files in the c.asspath

Comment: Thanks for the project @javaguest, let me try it.

Comment: Hello @javaguest, you seem to be using `4.3.0.Final` version of Hibernate which is working fine at my end too. The same code isn't working with Hibernate 5.0.x version. Could you test your code with Hibernate 5.0.x version and see if it's working?

Comment: I switched to 5.0.0 Final, and I could reproduce the issue. I edited my answer based on that.

Comment: Nothing needs to go into `configuration.buildSessionFactory()` call in the `HibernateUtil` class for the `Message` entity to be found. That way, you don't need to use `addAnnotatedClass` (E.g. `configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Message.class)`) as you would be able to do that in your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file using `<mapping class="entity.Message"/>`.

Comment: yes, i know, but configuration in 5.0 got a major overhaul. Apparently, to use a configuration xml file, you have to use JPA declarations. I'm still looking on how to do it non-programatically.

Comment: fixed it: more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33005348/hibernate-5-org-hibernate-mappingexception-unknown-entity/33134619?noredirect=1#comment54268230_33134619

Comment: Yep, build the `StandardServiceRegistry` first, then build the `Metadata` and then the `SessionFactory` using them.

Comment: It works for me using Hibernate 5.x
Why Hibernate always change his configuration setting in every version? :(

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could do the following in Hibernate 5+ and have your `SessionFactory`/`Session` creating class **`extend`** the `HibernateHelper` class below:

`package com.company.hibernatehelper;`

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateHelper {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if(sessionFactory == null) {
        sessionFactory = new  Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```